# jQuery Date and Time not modifying the HTML document

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function currentDate() {
    var now = new Date();
    var year = now.getFullYear();
    var month = now.getMonth();
    var day = now.getDay();
    var hours = now.getHours();
    var minutes = now.getMinutes();
    var seconds = now.getSeconds();

    var time = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
    var date = (day + "/" + month + "/" + year).toLocaleDateString();

    $('#time').html("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></span> " + time);
    $('#date').html("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-calendar'></span> " + date);

  }
  currentDate();
  setInterval(currentDate(), 1000);
});
```

This code doesn't seem to do anything... There are no errors...
It has been linked in the 'head'.

```
<script src="js/datetime.js"></script>
```

My elements are:

```
<div class="navbar-right" style="color:#fff;margin-right:0px;">
    <div class="navbar-brand" id="fade">
        <p id="date" title="Your Date."></p>
     </div>
     <div class="navbar-brand" id="fade">
        <p id="time" title="Your Time."></p>
     </div>
</div>
```

The webpage does not seem to show anything, at all in the places it should go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.toLocaleDateString() cannot be used with only date string. .toLocaleDateString() can be added to new Date(). If you use setInterval the function must called without brackets.

```
function currentDate() {
    var now = new Date();
    var year = now.getFullYear();
    var month = now.getMonth();
    var day = now.getDay();
    var hours = now.getHours();

    var minutes = now.getMinutes();
    minutes = (minutes < 10) ? '0'+minutes : minutes;

    var seconds = now.getSeconds();
    seconds = (seconds < 10) ? '0'+seconds : seconds;

    var time = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
    var date = (day + "/" + month + "/" + year);

    $('#time').html("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></span> " + time);
    $('#date').html("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-calendar'></span> " + date);

}
$(function() {
    currentDate();
    setInterval(currentDate, 1000);
});
```

Are you sure js/datetime.js is the right path to your file. Try with code inside the html :)

Comment: Please do not post only-code answers. Please explain your answer.

Comment: I Edit my post with some explanations

Answer (score 0):

1)

`setInterval` should take function variable. But in your case you called the function. Should be without braces:

```
setInterval(currentDate, 1000);
```

2)

You have duplicated ids `id="fade"`. Use unique ids.